# Can I disable the Emoji icon in UITextField?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, emoji

When I set the text of `UITextField` as "♈", it will display an emoji icon, but I just want to display the original character.

Comment: Isn't it original character of a specific font already? Can you get ".text" of the UITextField and check it symbol-by-symbol?

Comment: I just search and copy the "♈" from Chrome browser to Xcode, it seems everything is right, but when displayed in iPhone Simulator, it was converted to an Emoji icon..... The font of my UITextField is "[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.f]". How can I disable the Emoji support of my UITextField? Should I use another font instead?

Comment: What do you want to see instead of this symbol? It's a font symbol with specific code (2648 I believe), it is like letter 'Y' but with another glyph. If you want to see some code like "::ARIES::", you wouldn't.

Comment: lots of fonts include scalable black&white characters for some of the emoji codepoints, but iOS seems to replace them all with those colored, unscalable pixmaps. Sometimes it would be nice to use the character that the font provides!

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `\U0000FE0E` after the special character in your NSString. That will tell the OS to use the "plain" version and not to replace it with an emoji. See https://paulofierro.com/blog/2013/3/30/disabling-emoji-characters-with-unicode-variants

Answer (score 0):

if you want to ristrict the emoji insertion in text field then you can use the NSPredicates
or can check against the NSCharacterSet.

Comment: Thanks, but this is another topic of preventing input emoji. I don't want my characters displayed as icons....it is very strange. I am not sure if this can be done, maybe I should NOT use such special character in my strings.....

Comment: mak a char set you want in your string and make a checking function and call that function in UITextField delegate functions.